# How to enable zstd for your qcow2 files

Tags: kvm, qemu, qcow2

In QEMU 5.1 zstd compression of your qcow2 files was introduced.
But it's not described in the manual for qemu-img.
How do you enable it?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful : https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/5.1
It says Optional zstd compression for qcow2 (enable with compression_type=zstd as a creation option)

Comment: Yea, I already found that. I don't really know what it means though. Is it an option to be used when you compiled QEMU yourself? All I can find is these patch solutions/threads. But that has been an option for years it seems, so why advertise it as a new feature in version 5.1.....what's new?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a `zlib` compressed qcow2 image to `zstd` compressed one like this

```
qemu-img convert -c -O qcow2 -o compression_type=zstd ./input-file-name.qcow2 ./output-file-name_c.qcow2
```

Tested this today in `qemu-img` version 7.0.0

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an option for the `qemu-img create` command, so it's only possible to use zstd when creating new images e.g. `qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o compression_type=zstd ./test-with-zstd.qcow2 10`

I guess it provide continuous compression in contrast to the current "old" compression feature which didn't.