# Archive qemu image

Tags: gzip, archive, disk-image, qcow2, zstd

How do I archive qemu images with the same efficiency as gcloud

This command stub show efficiency. Around 80% on pre installed images of OSes notorious for their install size. 40g actual physical files on the disk on a fresh install archived as 5g file. Ready to uncompress and use

```
gcloud compute images describe
```

The command does not show the uncompressed file size. 40g is the output of `df` on a running image

My own attempt based on finding zero help on this is a disaster. Low efficiency. 20%. The OS is a whopping 30g and the results are only 25g

```
gzip qcow2

qemu-img convert -c -O qcow2 -o compression_type=zstd
```

References

[How to enable zstd for your qcow2 files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646735/how-to-enable-zstd-for-your-qcow2-files)

Comment: I am not familiar with `gcloud` so it is difficult for me to answer this question. You might get more answers or get them more quickly if you explained what this `gcloud` does. Image archiving can be accelerated with base images, snapshots, and compression.